# ManagementScope does not work through library

Tags: wmi

I have the following code which works directly from console application. If I put the code into a new library, it throws an exception only for certain types of DNS records though it works for others:

The below works fine:

```
ConnectionOptions connectionOptions = new ConnectionOptions();
connectionOptions.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;

ManagementScope managementScope = new ManagementScope(@"\\.\root\MicrosoftDNS", connectionOptions);         
managementScope.Connect();

if (managementScope.IsConnected)
{               
    Console.WriteLine("Connected.");
}

ManagementClass managementClass = new ManagementClass(existingManagementScope, new ManagementPath("MicrosoftDNS_MXType"), null);

ManagementBaseObject managementParams = managementClass.GetMethodParameters("CreateInstanceFromPropertyData");
managementParams["DnsServerName"] = "ns1.example.com";
managementParams["ContainerName"] = "example.com";
managementParams["OwnerName"] = "example.com";
managementParams["MailExchange"] = "mail.google.com.";
managementParams["Preference"] = 10;
managementParams["TTL"] = 90;

managementClass.InvokeMethod("CreateInstanceFromPropertyData", managementParams, null);
```

The below does not work:

```
MyDNSCMD dnscmd = new MyDNSCMD();
dnscmd.AddMXResourceRecord(ref managementScope, "example.com", "mail.google.com", 15, 90);
```

The below works though:

```
MyDNSCMD dnscmd = new MyDNSCMD();
dnscmd.AddAResourceRecord(ref managementScope, "example.com", "mail", "192.168.0.88", 90);
```

Comment: You need to a) show the code in both functions called in MyDNSCMD and b) detail what exceptions are thrown.

Comment: It seems that WMI based methods as long as they are in the same library work fine. But if they are in another library, they do not work due to permissions issue.

I have moved the class into the main application project and everything works fine.